# How does "optind" get assigned in C?

Tags: c, posix, getopt

I am creating this question because there is not much about how this optind gets assigned for each loop.

[Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) says :

> The variable optind is the index of the next element to be processed in argv. The system initializes this value to 1.

Below, I have a simple code I got from *Head First C* and in the code we **subtract** "*optind*" from "*argc*" and we get the number of leftover arguments, which will we use then to print leftover arguments as "Ingredients".

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
char* delivery = "";
int thick = 0 ;
int count = 0;

char ch;,

for(int i = 0; i < argc;i++){
//This is , to show the whole array and their indexes.
    printf("Argv[%i] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
while((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != -1 ){
    switch(ch) {
        case 'd':
            printf("Optind in case 'd' : %i\n",optind);
            delivery = optarg;
            break;
        case 't':
            printf("Optind in case 't' : %i\n",optind);
            thick = 1;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr,"Unknown option: '%s'\n", optarg); // optional argument.
            return 1;
    }
}
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    printf("Optind : %i and Argc after the subctraction : %i\n",optind,argc);
    if(thick)
        puts("Thick crust");
    if(delivery[0]){
        printf("To be delivered %s\n", delivery);
    }

    puts("Ingredients:");
    for(count = 0; count < argc ; count ++){
        puts(argv[count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So at the beginning of the code the for loop writes all the array and its indexes to see the difference.

Then I run the code with :

```
./pizzaCode -d now Anchovies Pineapple -t //-t is intentionally at the end
```

I was told that if the flag was at the end it wouldn't get in the 't' case but somehow it works on my ubuntu. That is another thing I wonder but not the main question.

So the output is as follows :

```
Argv[0] = ./pizzaCode
Argv[1] = -d
Argv[2] = now
Argv[3] = Anchovies
Argv[4] = Pineapple
Argv[5] = -t
Optind in case 'd' : 3
Optind in case 't' : 6
Optind : 4 and Argc after the subctraction : 2
Thick crust
To be delivered now
Ingredients:
Anchovies
Pineapple
```

1- Everything is fine so far, the problem is how come argv[0] and argv[1](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) became Anchovies and Pineapple ?

2- And another question is how did optind become 3 in case 'd'? Since 'd's index is 1 and the next index is 2.

3- How did optind become 4 after the loop ? It was 6 in the case 't'.

I hope my question is clear for you all, I am just trying to understand the logic instead of having to memorize it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why wouldn't the code get to the 't' option? What was the reasoning of whoever told you that? Perhaps some standards don't allow options after non-option arguments, but lots of programs accepts options after non-option arguments.

Comment: Why do you say `argv[0]` is "Anchovies"? The output shows it to be "./pizzaCode".

Comment: @Evert , someone told me it would be invalid and flag must be at the first indexes before anything. I don't know why but he was right though. When I ran my code online on jdoodle. It doesn't recognize "-t" as flag and returns it as a normal argument. That was odd.

Comment: @Evert , because at the end of the code we use a for loop to return the leftover arguments with a count starting from 0 to 2(exclusive). And that means argv[0] and argv[1] if I am not mistaken.

Comment: `optind` after 'd' is 3, because it skips over the `-d now` arguments, which have indices 1 and 2. The next argument to be processed is Anchovies, which has index 3 (in argv).

Comment: You might find the source code for getopt illuminating.  Here's one implementation (from GNU): https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/posix/getopt.c.html

Comment: This page, [Program Argument Syntax Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) (from the GNU C library) will also helps tremendously. It says: "The implementations of getopt and argp_parse in the GNU C Library normally make it appear as if all the option arguments were specified before all the non-option arguments for the purposes of parsing, even if the user of your program intermixed option and non-option arguments. They do this by reordering the elements of the argv array. This behavior is nonstandard" Which explains why optind=4 at the end.

Comment: In other words: GNU != POSIX.

Comment: @jdigital thank you I will take a look at the link.
Evert , and also having said that, I've added another for loop at the end of the code to write the whole array again and the array has been changed. There were only the leftover arguments in the array. That may explain the whole thing. Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [manpage for Gnu `getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) documents this non-standard implementation:

> By default, `getopt()` permutes the contents of `argv` as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.

This is actually not quite true; the permutation occurs after the last option is scanned, as you have seen in your example. But the effect is the same; `argv` is permuted so that nonoptions are at the end, and `optind` is modified to index the first nonoption.

If you want to avoid the permutation, so that `getopt` behaves as per Posix:

> If the first character of optstring is '+' or the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set, then option processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument is encountered.

In this case, no permuting is done and `optind`'s value is preserved.

Setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT` has other consequences, documented here and there in the manpages for various Gnu utilities. My habit is to use `+` as the first character of the option string (unless I actually want non-Posix behaviour), but arguably setting the environment variable is more portable.

---

For your specific questions:

1. Why are the non-option arguments at `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`?

   Because you modified argv: `argv += optind;`
2. Why is `optind` 3 in the loop processing option `-d`?

   Because that option takes an argument. So the *next* argument is the one following the `now` argument, which has already been processed (by placing a pointer to it into `optarg`).
3. How did `optind` become 4?

   As above, it was modified after the `argv` vector was permuted, in order for `optind` to be the index of the first "unprocessed" non-option argument.

Comment: Thank you so much!  One more thing, 'the permutation occurs after the last option is scanned' this is also why optind was 3 and 6 in the cases right? Like after the index of "now" and "-t".

You've made everything clear. Couldn't be explained better! :)

Comment: @PorFavorDama: `optind` is not moved backwards until the permutation takes place. So, yes, that is why it is still the index in the original argument vector.

Comment: It may be worth noting that using a `+` in the option string is undefined behavior.  For example, on various systems (NetBSD, FreeBSD, and Illumos) the leading `+` would be treated as a valid option character, leading to various incompatibilities.

Comment: @kdhp: that is not undefined behaviour.  Since you will not have a `case '+':` in your switch, the hypothetical `-+` option will trigger the `default` case, which should be implemented as an error action. (I agree that the fact that the gnu extension is opt-out instead of opt-in is sub-optimal.)

Comment: @rici By undefined behavior I meant that the standard only addresses alphanumeric options from the portable character-set, rather than the particular implementation.  However portability between those two categories of implementations fail in the case of `+:`, where the former implementation will suppress error messages, while the latter does not.

Comment: @kdhp: Yes, `+:` will certainly lead to incompatible behaviour, unless you set `opterr` to 0. I'd say that Posix leaves the consequences of using `+` as an option character unspecified rather than undefined, but it does say that such a string is not "maximally portable", which could be regarded as a warning. In practice, I've been using it for many years on a variety of implementations without running into trouble.

Comment: @rici That is a good point.  If `default` and `opterr` are used then I do not think that there is practical way for an implementation to disallow the leading `+`.